# How to know Button's array location using tag and a class?

Tags: c#

I am using WinForm to make an expanding board when clicked, essentialy what I need is to Get the Array Row and column, so I can send to a Class called place, that will take the pressed button and make its right, left, bottom and up buttons visible, How do I do that?. An example of the result will be attached.
PLEASE - do not suggest other idead than tag and a class, because i'm working under a teacher with very strict demands, ANND NOTE, keep things as simple as possible, I'm a Beginner with less than a year in Coding.
Thanks Ahead!
[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEVGB.jpg)

Clicking Function :

```
    private void qqq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //When Click
    {

       Place pl=(Place)( ((Button)sender).Tag());
```

Place Class :

```
class Place
{
    private int row;
    private int col;
    public Place(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
    private int GetR()
    {
        this.row = row;
    }
    private int GetC();
    {
        this.col = col;
    }
private int SetR()
{
    return row;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please post some code. Show us what you tried

Comment: You can specify [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) when creating buttons, it's of `object` type, so you can assign anything (but in form designer only `string`). How far are you and what is your problem?

Comment: Is you question how to move button?

Comment: `Tag` is a property, not method. Remove `()` after it.

Comment: @CoLiNaDE 
Just edited the post and added the code parts necessary.

Comment: @Sinatr then what? it will send the numbers to the class?

Comment: `pl` is the instance of class `Place` which you have to assign earlier, when creating button. Do you? Or is `pl == null`? Once you have valid instance you can change its *properties* (I wonder, why you didn't use any) and call methods. But changing `row` or `col` won't magically change button location on the form.

Comment: The code you posted doesnt even compile. GetR and GetC have a return type of int but they dont return anything. They should be called SetR and SetC and return void. Also they are useless since they are private. And your SetR method should be called GetR since it returns r.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
{
...

btn.Click += (sender, ev) => {
    var b = Button as sender;
    if (b != null)
    {
        var tag = b.Tag; // assuming tag is keeping row/col in form R_C
        var dims = tag.Split('_');
        var row = int.Parse(dims[0]);
        var col = int.Parse(dims[1]);

        // get the buttons around, if any and make visible
        SetButtonVisible($"{row - 1}_{col})";
        SetButtonVisible($"{row}_{col - 1}");
        SetButtonVisible($"{row}_{col + 1}");
        SetButtonVisible($"{row + 1}_{col + 1}");
    }
};

}

private void SetButtonVisible(string tag)
{
   var button = form.Controls
                    .OfType<Button>()
                    .SingleOrDefault( c => c.Tag == tag );
   if ( button != null)
   {
      button.Visible = true;
   }     
}
```

Comment: Kinda complicated for me..
I dont know what var is.

Comment: var should be on the first pages of a C# tutorial book. First you should learn the "ABC"s of C# before trying to Coe framework.